# How permanently kill dockerd?

Tags: linux, docker, service

When I run `top` in linux terminal I have:

```
 1147 root      20   0 1227548  34604   5784 S   1,7  0,9   1:10.88 dockerd
```

How can I kill it permanently? I know I can kill it manually by linux `kill`, but at the next work with computer `dockerd` will be shown again.

Comment: which OS or Linux flavor do you use / targeting ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*dockerd* is common Linux daemon, nothing more than that. You should disable it the way suitable for your OS, depending on system services manager used.

Here are some examples (docker service name may vary system to system). First command stops the service, second disables its launch on system start.

For systemd driven OS (e.g. Ubuntu 16.04, RHEL/CentOS 7, Arch Linux), that will be:

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
sudo systemctl disable docker
```

For docker installed via snap:

```
sudo snap stop docker
sudo snap disable docker
```

For relatively old Ubuntu (before 15.10), using Upstart service manager:

```
sudo service docker stop
sudo sh -c 'echo manual > /etc/init/docker.override'
```

For older CentOS6 and some others:

```
sudo service dockerd stop
sudo chkconfig dockerd off
```

et cetera

You should look for instructions on how to disable service for specific OS you're interested in